# Side bar stop when hitting footer

Tags: javascript, footer, sidebar, sticky

I have tried a lot of the suggestions on here but none seem to work.
I'm trying to stop a side bar "div class="fixed-col-left fixed-left" from going over the footer on small screens.

```
<section class="contain-main">
<div class="center-div inner-col-2">
<div class="fixed-col-main">
<div class="fixed-col-left fixed-left"></div>
<div class="fixed-col-right"></div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<footer class="footer-main"></footer>
```

So far I have come to this JS result but it still doesn't seem to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.fn.scrollBottom = function() {
            return $(document).height() - this.scrollTop() - this.height();
        };

        var $el = $('#fixed-col-left>div');
        var $window = $(window);

        $window.bind("scroll resize", function() {
            var gap = $window.height() - $el.height() - 10;
            var visibleFoot = 400 - $window.scrollBottom();
            var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop()

            if(scrollTop < 400 + 10){
                $el.css({
                    top: (400 - scrollTop) + "px",
                    bottom: "auto"
                });
            }else if (visibleFoot > gap) {
                $el.css({
                    top: "auto",
                    bottom: visibleFoot + "px"
                });
            } else {
                $el.css({
                    top: 0,
                    bottom: "auto"
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Video demo showing what is happening.
    http://sendvid.com/vfbv7pvd

Comment: Could you provide fiddle or something like that and I will help you. Or add css.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the CSS definition that says:

```
 .fixed-col-left.fixed-left {
    position: fixed;
    top: 113px;
  }
```

The `position: fixed` is causing it to overlap, and setting the `position` attribute to `absolute` in your script will cause the overlap to stop happening.

Comment: Hi Mike.
Sorry, it was a typo for the </footer?

Comment: Here is a link to the page
http://www.newcastlenow.org.au/what-we-do/now

Comment: Changing the css from `fixed` to `absolute` stops the fixed menu.

Comment: Do you mean adding the class in the JS?

Comment: @ChrisStonestreet you could get rid of the class, and instead add in the `position: fixed`  and `position: absolute`  tags to the `$el.css()`  functions to get it to change dynamically